# Is there a way to create a code placeholder in Visual Studio without using snippets?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If I'm in the process of manually copying multiple similar lines of code in Visual Studio, is there a way to create placeholders for the pieces of text that need to be changed? This can be accomplished by creating a code snippet, but that seems like a lot of work for one off jobs.

I remember XCode supported this feature way back in my Objective-C days.

Example:

```
List<string> listOfStrings = new();

//I will be copying this line of code 50 times
listOfStrings.Add("String 1");
```

Instead of manually copying, pasting, and highlighting the string value, I'm looking for a shorthand that would allow me to duplicate the line, and tab directly to the value needing replaced.

```
listOfStrings.Add("[tab_highlights_this]")
```

Comment: What if instead of using <kbd>Tab</kdb> to highlight, you use <kbd>F3</kbd>?  F3 is the default shortcut for "Repeat last Find".

Comment: You can [use regular expressions to find and replace anything](https://davidsonsousa.net/blog/post/use-regular-expressions-on-visual-studio-to-find-and-replace-anything) or use [Multi-caret editing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/multi-caret-editing?view=vsmac-2022). But there are still some inconveniences compared to code snippets.